# postman send string containing forward slash to web api get method

Tags: .net, web-services, special-characters, query-string, postman

I have the following web api method:

```
[HttpGet("{param}")]
public IEnumerable<ResultItem> MyMethod(string param)
```

I need to pass a string with special characters to the web api method. I have tried the following from postman but none of them works. Specifically, I need to pass URL to the method. I find out it has problem with forward slash.

(1) This works: http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/hello

(2) This obviously doesn't work: http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/https://www.google.com

(3) Works but the forward slashes do NOT appear in the input parameter of the method. Only "http:".

```
http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http:/
http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http://
http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http:%2F
http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http:%2F%2F
```

(4) Doesn't work. Yes, strange enough, the method is not reached at all after adding a character after the forward slash. Fiddler shows HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.
    http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http:/a
    http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http://a
    http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http:%2Fa
    http://localhost:1234/api/MyController/MyMethod/http:%2F%2Fa

Any advice and insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you need to uri encode it, so you arent sending illegal characters or characters in illegal positions

Comment: Doesn't my option (3) urlencode the string?

Comment: not completely, you need to encode the `.`

Comment: How to do that from Postman?

Comment: According to https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html the period is not considered a special character. No?

Comment: its not a special character but its not allowed to be in the url apart from the domain part

Comment: Don't think so. See my option (4)

Comment: do you decode it in your web api? like in the server code?

Comment: It doesn't reach the method at all

Comment: are you sure the call matches the data handler?

Comment: Check my (1) to (4) above. They all differ only in the string parameter but have the same URL

Comment: well it appears that the web handler doesnt like the call